# TimeZone do Brasil para DateTimeOffset C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

Gostaria de saber quais são os possíveis *TimeZones* disponíveis para todas as regiões do Brasil.

Vi que temos o **E. South America Standard Time** para o horário de brasília, porém por exemplo, qual seria o *TimeZone* do Acre?

Comment: Acre é `America/Rio_Branco`. Veja tudo que tem "BR" aqui: https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2018g/zone1970.tab#L85

Comment: No meu caso eu estou utilizando da seguinte forma: TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. South America Standard Time"); Porém com America/Rio_Branco não da certo :(

Comment: Ah, deve ser porque o C# usa os nomes de timezones do Windows (e não sei se tem um específico para o Acre), enquanto `America/Rio_Branco` está na lista da IANA - veja a diferença entre eles aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info (veja a seção "Time Zone Databases")

Comment: Valeu amigo, dei uma pesquisada e usando o framework TimeZoneConverter da para utilizar os TimeZones da lista da IANA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu achei na documentação o método `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()`, que:

> [TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones)
>
> Retorna uma coleção classificada de todos os fuso horários sobre os quais há informações disponíveis no sistema local.

E na documentação da função `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById()`, que o autor da pergunta está usando, diz o seguinte:

> [TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(String) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid)
>
> Recupera um objeto `TimeZoneInfo` do Registro com base em seu identificador.
>
> Em sistemas Windows, `FindSystemTimeZoneById` tenta corresponder id para os nomes da subchave da ramificação do registro `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`.

Usei o método:

```
// Retorna uma coleção do tipo
// System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo>.
var timeLista = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
```

Separei alguns dos itens retornados, e também analisei esses itens no *Registry* do Windows, em `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`, e finalmente cheguei à seguinte lista:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|                   DisplayName                    |          StandardName           |          DaylightName           |
+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| (UTC-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito, Rio Branco      | SA Pacific Standard Time        | SA Pacific Daylight Time        |
| (UTC-04:00) Cuiaba                               | Central Brazilian Standard Time | Central Brazilian Daylight Time |
| (UTC-04:00) Georgetown, La Paz, Manaus, San Juan | SA Western Standard Time        | SA Western Daylight Time        |
| (UTC-03:00) Araguaina                            | Tocantins Standard Time         | Tocantins Daylight Time         |
| (UTC-03:00) Brasilia                             | E. South America Standard Time  | E. South America Daylight Time  |
| (UTC-03:00) Cayenne, Fortaleza                   | SA Eastern Standard Time        | SA Eastern Daylight Time        |
| (UTC-03:00) Salvador                             | Bahia Standard Time             | Bahia Daylight Time             |
+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Entendi, dei uma testada com os timezones citados e deu tudo certo! Valeu Pedro :)